# Solving Linear Systems Ax=b Using Iteration

Tags: calculus, matrices, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, numerical-methods

Question:
Let's assume $A$ is a nonsingular matrix and we will use the iteration $$x+δr \to x$$ to solve for $Ax=b$, where $r=b-Ax$. We choose $δ$ in order to minimize the function $\phi(x)={\|Ax-b\|}_2^2$ where $x$ has vectors of the form $x+δr$. Justify whether the iterative method would converge.

Confusion: The approach i thinking is to find a $r\ne0$ s.t. $d=0$. But I do not really understand the minimization function $\phi(x)={\|Ax-b\|}_2^2$ and how would i find a $r=0$ to minimize it? Or is it better to find the standard iterative matrix first? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify, what is $r$, $d$ and where you pull $n$ and $k$ from in your "confusion"-part?

Comment: sorry for n, k i used the wrong letters; but d is the step size

Comment: i used d as lower case delta

Comment: Why did you duplicate your original question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2724346/115115 from 4h ago?

Comment: sorry they're actually different and the old one is worded much more confusingly so ill delete it my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all in one formula and see what happens
$$
\|Ax_+-b\|^2=\|A(x+\delta r)-b\|^2=\|r+δAr\|^2=\|r\|^2+2δ\langle r,\,Ar\rangle+δ^2\|Ar\|^2
$$
The minimum of this quadratic polynomial happens for $δ=-\dfrac{⟨r,Ar⟩}{∥Ar∥^2}$, the value of the quadratic there is $\|r\|^2-\dfrac{⟨r,Ar⟩^2}{∥Ar∥^2}$. So you want that $⟨r,Ar⟩=0$, $r\perp Ar$ for some $r=Ax-b\ne 0$.

As $2⟨r,Ar⟩=⟨r,(A+A^\top)r⟩$, this would be possible if the symmetric part of $A$ has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: please explain what you meant by the last statement? what do you mean by the symmetric part of A? I know that a square matrix whose kernel is {0} is invertible, so that the nonsingular matrix here does not have a nontrivial matrix since its kernel is {0}, am i right?

Comment: bump? thanks again

Comment: An anti-symmetric matrix can be invertible, however by anti-symmetry $r^TAr=0$ for all $r$. That is the reason why for a quadratic functional you select the symmetric form for the coefficient matrix, here $\frac12(A+A^T)$.

Comment: sorry the way i understood is more basic: (Ar, r) has to be 0 without r being 0 and an example i come up with is $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=0$$ but i do not understand what you mean by symmetric form? like ccould you explain in more details how i would be able to obtain (Ar,r)=0 using the symmetric matrix you talked bout?

Comment: i guess more speficially how do i find out if the symmetric part of nonsingular matrix has nontraivial kernel?

Comment: You do not need to. You only need to know that examples exist to invalidate the claim that the iteration always finds the solution. Look up again what anti- or skew-symmetric matrices are.